# Search specific format value in database field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have to search for specific format values in a database field. Value format as below:

```
ABC 1167:YYYY
ABC 45870:YYYY
ABC 7654:YYYY
ABC 45076:YYYY
```

`YYYY`- could be a year i.e. 2018, 2019

I tried to use `Format()` function as well as tried with RegEX but it's not getting results as expected.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know the range of years?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its mostly 2018 & 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am assuming that atleast 4 digits will follow 'ABC ' and post the digits you will have `:` and followed by years '2018' or '2019'

```sql
DECLARE @table TABLE(charValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
('ABC 1167:2018'),
('ABC 45870:2019'),
('ABC 7654:2018'),
('ABC 45076:2019');

SELECT * FROM @table
WHERE charValue LIKE 'ABC [0-9][0-9][0-9]%:201[8-9]'
```

```
+----------------+
|   charValue    |
+----------------+
| ABC 1167:2018  |
| ABC 45870:2019 |
| ABC 7654:2018  |
| ABC 45076:2019 |
+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only expect `20xx` years, you could try:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]:20[0-9][0-9]';
```